# Rails has_one and has_many association on the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a users model and a groups model.

A user `has_and_belongs_to_many  :groups` and a group `has_and_belongs_to_many  :users`.
The associations and join tables work correctly.

A group can only have one user who owns the group, I want to name be able to call `@group.owner` to return the user that owns the group but am unsure of how to do it, I've created a user references column on the Group table `rails g migration add_user_to_groups user:references`
but I don't know what to put in the Group model, something like `has_one :user, as: :owner`

Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
has_one :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: 'user_id'
```

Comment: What you mean to say is, `has_one` throws error for you ?